# How to pipe Where-Object output into Azure AD Group

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

After a group member has enrolled for MFA, I need to remove the member from one 
Azure AD group and add them to another group.

When I run the script I receive no errors, but it does not remove/add members as expected. I can verify it makes it through Step 2 but does nothing after that. I believe I need a `Select-Object` in the beginning of Step 3.

*Script will remove members from Group A and move them to Group B if the member has enrolled in MFA.*

1. `Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "7d23abf4-4e30-4092-b4e6-a5297addad75" |`
2. `Where-Object {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $null} |`
3. `Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "24db4ad9-8fe0-45f6-a71a-79b76395105a" |`
4. `Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "7d23abf4-4e30-4092-b4e6-a5297addad75"`

   ```
   Step 1. Get member of Group A
   Step 2. Where member has enrolled in MFA 
   Step 3. Add member to Group B
   Step 4. Remove member from Group A
   ```

Script should audit one Azure Ad group (A) to see which members have enrolled in MFA, remove those who have enrolled from the group, and move them to another group (B).

Comment: Script runs as a one-liner with each step piping into the other (minus the step numbers of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues about your script.

1.The `|` means powershell pipline, it is not such usage, more details see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6).

2.The [`User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) entity in `AzureAD` powershell does not have the `StrongAuthenticationMethods` property, it exists in the [`MSOnline powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-1.0), so you need to use that instead.

Here is a sample for you, make sure you have installed the `MSOnline` powershell module with `Install-Module MSOnline`.

**Note**: You need to make sure the users are not already in the Group B, otherwise you will get an error `The group member you are trying to add is already a member of this group`.

```
Connect-MsolService

$groupA = "<objectid of group A>"
$groupB = "<objectid of group B>"

#get the users(whose GroupMemberType is 0) in the group A
$userids = (Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupA | Where-Object {$_.GroupMemberType -eq '0'}).ObjectId
#add the MFA-enrolled user to A and remove from B
foreach($item in $userids){
    $user = Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $item
    if($user.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -ne "0"){
        Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupB -GroupMemberType User -GroupMemberObjectId $item
        Remove-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupA -GroupMemberType User -GroupMemberObjectId $item

    }else{
        Write-Host The user $user.DisplayName is not MFA-enrolled.
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! Joy, This worked perfectly right out-of-the-box. I am very thankful for your time and effort.

Comment: I have one questions if you get time. I understand everything you did in the script except $_.GroupMemberType -eq '0'. I don't understand what that is doing. It works perfectly, I would just like to know so I can be better. Thank you again.

Comment: @AlanInman The `0` represents `User`, because there could be also groups or service principal in the group.